# Client side PDF encryption at time of creation

Tags: encryption, pdf-generation

I am using React PDF and to create and export PDF documents.

I want to be able to have the user upload contents to their client side cache, and then serve back the content in a password protected encrypted PDF file.

I do not want them to upload files to the server.

Are there any free, open source solutions to achieve client side PDF encryption / password protection?

The PDF would be generated on browser including phones / iOS and tablets and desktops.

Comment: If AGPL is free enough for you, there is https://github.com/coherentgraphics/coherentpdf.js

Comment: THANKS! Does this do it client side without requiring the files be uploaded to a server?

We don't want to take on responsibility for the transmission or storage of the data... so it should all be in the local user cache.

Comment: Yes, it's just a single blob of JS, which processes data entirely in the browser.

Comment: @johnwhitington are there any solutions with MIT license you know of?

Comment: I'm not, I'm afraid.